# The last characters in my C-style string are odd values when I

Tags: c++, string

for our assignment we have to work with C-style strings in C++, and reverse an input, however when I have a string of 6 or more characters it outputs the reversed string as well as some garbage values. Any help for fixing this is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int SIZE = 11;
    char name[SIZE];


    cout << "Please enter a name of 10 characters or less ";
    cin.getline(name, SIZE);


    char *stringStart, *stringEnd;
    stringStart = name;
    stringEnd = &name[strlen(name)-1];
    char backwardsName[SIZE];
    int i = 0;

    // Appending each element to backwardsName starting with last character from name and decrementing.
    while (stringEnd >= stringStart)
    {

        backwardsName[i] = *stringEnd;
        ++i;
        --stringEnd;
    }

    cout << backwardsName << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using pointers to even ending the backwardsName string with a NULL character '\0' to no avail. The pointers did the same thing. The NULL character did help, but it started to break down when strings were 8 or more characters (*I think*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `NUL` termination. You did not put a `\0` after reversing `backwardsName`.

```
backwardsName[i] = '\0';
cout << backwardsName << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I did something stupid like backwards[I+1] or backwards[strlen(name)+1] when I initialized the element of the array to the null character.